# ¿Como dejar espacios vacíos en una fila?

Tags: javascript, bucle-for

Como puedo hacer para que al dividir 40 espacios entre un numero impar no muestre en los espacios vacíos como undefined.
[![Tengo la duda de como implementar en esa parte del código que deje espacio vacíos en la parte que no entra ningún[image: Eso es lo que sale en los espacios vacíos]

Comment: Creo que no está del todo claro el planteo, te sugiero leer el apartado ¿Como preguntar?, con la información adecuada será más sencillo ayudarte y evitas la posibilidad de que te cierren la pregunta.

Comment: @LuisS.Romero una sugerencia... si les dices que lean el apartado [ask] mejor que se lo digas con el enlace directamente. Es decir, cuando lo escribas pon simplemente `Léete [ask]` y eso se traducirá en **Léete [ask]** (lo importante no es el **Léete** claro, sino el `[ask]`)

Comment: Lo más importante: puedes poner el código? Las imágenes no compilan

Comment: @masterguru no sabía ese dato... que otras etiquetas como `[ask]` existen? hay un link para ver todas las que hayan disponibles?

Comment: Puedes ver mas informacion aqui https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242306

Comment: @masterguru Que bueno volver a leerte, muchas gracias, no tenía ese dato, lo aplicaré en futuros comentarios.

Comment: @LuisS.Romero sí, llevábamos un tiempo sin coincidir :-)  Pero no quiero quitarle el mérito a AndresGardiol que es el que te ha pasado el enlace, que yo no tenia, pero un dia si que lo vi y me acordaba de las más importantes, el `[ask]` y el `[tour]` que son las que uso con más frecuencia... pero ahora seguro que me aprenderé más pues ya conozco mejor el funcionamiento de este sitio